# IOS Download all file in folder on google drive using API

Tags: ios, google-api, google-drive-api

I using Google api v3 in ios app. Now i want to download all file and folder in folder determined with FolderID. But google API don't support download folder (i don't see download it here :https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/folder).
I looking for resolve everywhere but it not result. I try write my method download using recursive but it not working.
I think google drive API support it, but i don't find it.

If you have a solve or method problem solving you can help me.

Thank for reading.

### Update my code

Create query file in folder

```
-(void)downloadItemWithFolderID:(NSString *)FolderID writeToPath:(NSString *)writeToPath{
GTLRDriveQuery_FilesList *query = [GTLRDriveQuery_FilesList query];
query.fields = @"nextPageToken, files(id, name, mimeType)";
query.pageSize = 10;
query.q = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"'%@' In parents and trashed=false",FolderID];

[self.service executeQuery:query
                  delegate:self
         didFinishSelector:@selector(downloadFilePaten:finishedWithObject:error:)];
}
```

using recursive download all item. But how to pass folder name from create to method default `@selector(downloadFilePaten:finishedWithObject:error:)` ?

```
- (void)downloadFilePaten:(GTLRServiceTicket *)ticket
         finishedWithObject:(GTLRDrive_FileList *)result
                      error:(NSError *)error {
if (error == nil) {
    if (result.files.count > 0) {
        for (GTLRDrive_File *files in result.files) {
            if(![files.mimeType  isEqual: @"application/vnd.google-apps.folder"]){
                GTLRQuery *query = [GTLRDriveQuery_FilesGet queryForMediaWithFileId:files.identifier];
                [self.service executeQuery:query completionHandler:^(GTLRServiceTicket *ticket,
                                                                     GTLRDataObject *file,
                                                                     NSError *error) {
                    if (error == nil) {
                        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
                        NSString  *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
                        NSLog(@"documentsDirectory%@",documentsDirectory);

                        NSString  *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", documentsDirectory,files.name];
                        [file.data writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];

                        NSLog(@"Downloaded %lu bytes", file.data.length);

                    } else {
                        NSLog(@"An error occurred: %@", error);
                    }
                }];
                NSLog(@"run here");
            }else{
                NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
                NSString  *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

                [self saveFolderToPath:documentsDirectory folderName:files.name];
                [self downloadItemWithFolderID:files.identifier writeToPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",documentsDirectory,files.name]];
            }
        }
    } else {
        NSLog(@"%@", @"No files found.");
    }
} else {
    NSLog(@"Error getting presentation data: %@\n", error.localizedDescription);
}
}
```

write folder

```
-(void)saveFolderToPath:(NSString*)path folderName:(NSString*)name{
NSString *fl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@",name];
NSString * yourPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",path,fl];;
NSError * error = nil;
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath: yourPath
                          withIntermediateDirectories:YES
                                           attributes:nil
                                                error:&error];
}
```

Comment: There is no download folder.   You will need to list all of the files within your folder and download them one at a time recursively.   You will need to show your code if you would like assistance in debugging your issue.

Comment: @DaImTo
I update my code but how to pass folder name when using recursive

Comment: You need to edit your question and add your code. No one can help you debug what they can not see.   File.list returns a list of files.  You dont need a folder name when downloading, just the file id

Comment: @DaImTo sorry. i fix it

Answer (score 0):

The way Google Drive works is not like your folders on your desktop. Folders don't really have a tree shape, rather each file (and folder) lists its parent**s**.

Moreover, each file (or folder) is identified by its ID, and as you can see, there is no *download this folderID please* in the Google API. That means you can't directly download a folder.

You can come up with a swift (or python) script to do that, but you can't directly do what you want in a single API call.

Comment: This is right. But if we make Sync using download only file. we are have a very problem :(.

Comment: Well its not a Big problem. Thats what building Software and apps is about

Comment: If you know objective c you can edit my code ?. I don't pass new folder name

Comment: SO is not a coding service